# Why would a DIV position it's content according to another DIV's styles when they are using display:table-cell?

Tags: html, css

So I am converting the site over to HTML5, and losing the  tags... All was going great until I started working with my sidebar and content region.

When any element inside the `<section id="content">` is givin a margin-top (*#first-article*) for example, (or when the `<section id="content">` is given padding), the contents of `<nav id="sidebar">` are positioned down at the same Y-coordinate as the #content text.

**Notice I didn't say that the #sidebar contents receive the same style.** There is no *padding-top*, *margin*, *postion: top:X*, or anything in the computed style that would position these elements at the same Y coordinate.

I am fairly inexperienced when it come to creating  layouts (and other HTML5 block elements). So for me to get this far, it's fairly amazing lol. I am very versed in css in every other way however, which is why this is making me pull my hair out...

I used the **display: table-cell** style to position the **#sidebar** and **#content**. I am sure this has something to do with it. Unfortunately, this is the only way I have managed to get the code to do what I want it to.

***If you guys could give me some advice here, I would appreciate it very much! In the meantime, I will be doing more research on this. Thanks in advance everyone :)***

**Note:** *I am using the **html5-boilerplate** files '**normalize.css**', and '**main.css**' in addition to my styles (below). They don't seem to be contributing to my issue though...*

**Example** - [My Issue Example](http://www.horsepowerfreaks.com/cleanup/start.asp)

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div id="page">

  <header id="head">

   <img id="logo" src="/Images/head/logo-gloss-white.png">

   <nav id="account">
    <ul>
     <li id="phone">Call (503) 256-5600</li>
     <li>Logout</li>
     <li>My Cart (3)</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

  </header>

  <nav id="main">
   Main Menu
  </nav>

  <nav id="search-bar">
   Select Vehicle and Searchbox
  </nav>

  <nav id="crumbs">
   Directory Tree
  </nav>

  <section id="content-wrap">

    <nav id="sidebar">
      <ul>
       <li>
        <span>Nav</span>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="content">

      <article id="first-article">

       <p>Ecommerce Tracking - Before Google Analytics can report ecommerce activity for your website, you must enable ecommerce tracking on the profile settings page for your website. After that, you must implement the ga.js ecommerce tracking methods in your shopping cart pages or through your ecommerce software. The collection of ecommerce methods work together to send each user's transaction information to the Google Analytics database as it occurs. In this way, Analytics can link a specific referral source to a conversion or purchase. Most template-driven ecommerce engines can be modified to include this information hidden in the order confirmation page.</p>

       <ul>
        <li>General Process</li>
        <li>Guidelines</li>
        <li>Complete Example</li>
        <li>General Process</li>
       </ul>

       <p>The basic process for tracking ecommerce using Google Analytics can best be described by summarizing the three methods required for tracking ecommerce transactions on your site. These methods are described in the order in which you should invoke them in your shopping cart or ecommerce software.</p>
       <p>Create a transaction object. - Use the _addTrans() method to intialize a transaction object. The transaction object stores all the related information about a single transaction, such as the order ID, shipping charges, and billing address. The information in the transaction object is associated with its items by means of the order IDs for the transaction and all items, which should be the same ID.</p>

       <p>Add items to the transaction. - The _addItem() method tracks information about each individual item in the user's shopping cart and associates the item with each transaction via the orderId field. This method tracks the details about a particular item, such as SKU, price, category, and quantity.</p>

       <p>Submit the transaction to the Analytics servers. - The _trackTrans() method confirms that a purchase has occurred, and all data that has been built up in the transaction object is finalized as a transaction.</p>

       <p>There are many ways that this information can be retrieved from the ecommerce engine. Some ecommerce engines write the purchase information to a hidden form that you can use, others keep the information in a database that you can retrieve, and others store the information in a cookie. Some of the more popular ecommerce engines that recognize Google Analytics provide their own modules to simplify order tracking for Analytics.</p>

      </article>

    </section>

  </section>

</div>

<footer id="footer">
 Footer
</footer>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
body {
    background:#121212 url(/images/body/pageBg.jpg) repeat-x top;
    font-size:12px;
    clor:#333;
}

div#page {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;

    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

header#head {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    background:#121212 url(/images/head/headMetal.jpg) no-repeat right;
    border-bottom:#000 1px solid;
}

nav#main {
    height:44px;
    background:#121212 url(/images/menu/navBarBg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

nav#search-bar {
    height:50px;
    background:#f70 url(/images/menu/orangeBarBg.jpg) repeat-x;
    border-bottom:#F50 1px solid;
}

nav#crumbs {
    color:#575647;
    height:34px;
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:#eee 1px solid;
}

section#content-wrap {
    background:#e0e0e0;
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#sidebar {
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px;
    background:#fff;
    border-right:#ccc 1px solid;

    border-radius:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#content {
    display:table-cell;
    height:500px;
    padding:15px;
}

footer#footer {
    width:970px;
    margin:0px auto;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:15px;
    height:180px;
    padding:15px;

    background:#1e1e1e url(/images/footer/footBg.jpg) repeat-x center;

    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#page, #footer {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000; /* Safari, Chrome */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000; /* CSS3 */
}

/* Content */
/*----------------------- This is to demonstrate the issue at hand ------*/
#first-article {
    margin-top:100px;
}

/* Head Area */
img#logo {
    margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

nav#account {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

nav#account {
    margin:0;
}

nav#account li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `display: table-cell`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `table-cell` thing most likely has everything to do with it.  You're forcing 2 elements to act like they are table cells.  A nature table cell (a `td` element), falls inline with other `td`s that unless there is a `tr` or `display:table-row` separating them.  Those `td`s will naturally have the same height unless they have a `rowspan` > 1.  This means that if you change the `margin-top` or `padding` of one of them, it will affect the other `td`s in the same `tr`.

On top of these issues in modern browsers, earlier browsers (like IE < 8) do not support `display:table-[anything]` anyway, so you'd need backward-compatibility fixes there.  I imagine there's no real need for you to use `display:table-cell` because you can likely handle all your positioning through `float`s and standard positioning techniques.

There are plenty of methods for making 2 adjacent 'columns' equal height even though their content heights vary.  Check out this [article](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) for that.  This might help you to steer clear of the `table-cell` displays.

Comment: -Thats what I thought... Well I tried all kinds of combinations of positioning with the #sidebar and #content. The display:table-cell was the only combo that enabled the sidebar to fill the height of the container when the content area was longer, and vice-versa. I tried some absolute positioning with top:0; bottom:0 on the sidebar (inside and out of the #content) and nothing worked quite how I needed it. To be honest, the elements were acting quite odd. Not sure if it's the HTML5 that I'm not used to but... Any pointers/adjustments to get the equivalent result would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried the #content-wrap position:relative, the #sidebar position:absolute / float:left / top:0 / bottom:0, and #content float:right ________. So idk. Still looking at tuts on the topic. Thanks for the input :)!

Comment: Check out the article I posted above in the last paragraph for equal-height divs

Comment: Aside from the new html 5 elements, there's not much different in positioning. if you have a lot of experience in CSS, use what you know, but apply it to the new semantic elements. You'll also need html5shim or another helper to make yourself backward compatible while you use and style these elements.

Comment: No problem.  I hope this solved your problem.  Good luck with the html5 transition.